# Nano (pico) editor window resize

Tags: shell, terminal.app, nano, pico

I am still not sure what I have done but I was testing some button combinations when I was in nano editor and all of a sudden the contents of the window started not to adjust themselves when I resized the terminal window and everything becomes a huge mess. It is an ssh connection to an ubuntu machine and version is GNU nano 2.2.2. Below is an example of what happens when I resize from fullscreen to something smaller. This happens only for nano editor. Everything else works fine. Anyone has an idea ?

[image]

Comment: What OS version? What version of nano? You might have better luck getting answers on http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's actually an ssh connection to an Ubuntu machine using terminal. Version is GNU Nano 2.2.2

Comment: Ah…that makes a huge difference. On the remote machine, what is the value of the `TERM` environment variable? Does the command `infocmp` display an error or does it succeed?

Comment: $TERM variable is: xterm-color and infocmp seems to succeed by printing out some garbage (at least they don't make sense to me)